# Flip half of a list and append it to itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im trying to flip half of the elements inside of a list and then spend it onto itself, for example,
if I pass the list [1, 8, 7, 2, 9, 18, 12, 0] into it, I should get [1, 0, 7, 18, 9, 2, 12, 8] out, here is my current code

```
def flip_half(list):
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            listflip = list[i] 
            print(listflip)
    
            
    return list
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly assign slices in python. So if you can determine the slice you want to assign from and to, you can directly change the elements. This assign from every other element in reverse `l[::-2]` to every other element starting with the second: `l[1::2]` :

```
l = [1, 8, 7, 2, 9, 18, 12, 0]

l[1::2] = l[::-2]
print(l)
#[1, 0, 7, 18, 9, 2, 12, 8]
```

Comment: but this code has uncorrect result with odd length.

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) that the question is meaningful with an odd length input.

Comment: I agree with you. Not clear task. I think safe version is ```l[1::2] = l[1::2][::-2]```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it in a loop:

```
def flip_half(list):
    out = []
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            out.append(list[-i])
        else: 
            out.append(list[i])
    return out

print(flip_half([1, 8, 7, 2, 9, 18, 12, 0]))
```

Comment: or ```[list[i] if i % 2 == 0 else list[-(i + len(list)%2)] for i in range(len(list))]```

Answer (score 0):

If you need that elements with odd indexes has reverse order then one of next solutions (`l` - is your list):

*Slices*

```
l[1::2] = l[1::2][::-1]
```

*List comprehension*

```
l = [l[i] if i % 2 == 0 else l[-(i + len(l)%2)] for i in range(len(l))]
```

*Function*

```
def flip_half(lst):
    res= []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            res.append(lst[-(i + len(lst) % 2)])
        else: 
            res.append(lst[i])
    return res

l = flip_half(l)
```

*Generator function*

```
def flip_half(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            yield lst[-(i + len(lst) % 2)]
        else: 
            yield lst[i]

l = list(flip_half(l))
```